# How do you call EnableNonClientDpiScaling on a DialogBox dialog?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, dpi, highdpi

On a system without Per-Monitor v2 support, how do you enable DPI scaled non-client areas on a `DialogBox` dialog?

You are supposed to call [`EnableNonClientDpiScaling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablenonclientdpiscaling) in `WM_NCCREATE` but this message is not sent to `DialogBox` dialogs!

Answer (score 1):

Setting a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` thread [hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) before calling `DialogBox` and calling `EnableNonClientDpiScaling` on the first received `WM_NCCREATE` message does seem to work but it feels like a giant hack.

I suppose you could try to verify that the `HWND` is a dialog with your `DLGPROC` to make it a little more robust but still not ideal.

Comment: Is this still the correct answer Anders?  I ask because I have the same problem now.  For some reason my app doesn't recognise the _V2 in my manifest.  I have per monitor settings, but not the _V2 with automatic scaling.  I somehow need to tell dialogs to EnableNonClientDpiScaling.

Comment: @Robinson How do you know V2 did not apply? Did you call GetWindowDpiAwarenessContext? Focus on getting V2 working, V1 is too much of a pain for dialogs IMHO.

Comment: Reason I know is because I have to EnableNonClientDpiScaling in WM_NCCREATE to get the effect.  I call GetWindowDpiAwarenessContext and it returns DPI_AWARENESS_PER_MONITOR_AWARE.  Thing is, the enum doesn't have a DPI_AWARENESS_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 member.  I can't get a WM_NCCREATE from the hook either, strangely enough.  It's an awful hack anyway.  Question is, do I need the W11 SDK to do this correctly.  I have the latest W10.

Comment: V2 was added in 1703 so I'd guess your SDK is new enough, besides, the SDK version does not matter, what matters is your manifest. I have not looked at that in ages but I think there is a registry value you can add to get more SxS logging to debug manifest parsing.